# Assistance with a return method

Tags: java

I need assistance with a method that looks like below, I need to return the radius with one decimal all help is appreciated and I am supposed to use the Decimal format to do so.

```
public double beraknaOmkrets()
{
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.0");

    double omkrets = 0;
    omkrets = radie*2*3.14;
    return f.format(omkrets).toString;
}
```

Comment: *"I need to return the radius with one decimal"*  Are you certain that is the requirement?  More commonly we would return a `double` from `getRadius()` and a `String` from `getRadiusAsString()` (or something like that).  I am not sure what `beraknaOmkrets` translates to (please use English), but I would tend to use `getRadius()` and use `getRadiusAsString()` only when needed for presenting the radius as a `String`.

Comment: berakna omkrets: compute the circumference

Answer (score 1):

1. You forgot the parenthesis at the end of the `toString()` method
   call.
2. Your method signature is `double` but you try to return a
   `String`. Change the return type to `String`.

By the way you could merge the 2 omkrets init lines to only one, no need to initialize it to 0 if you change its value next line: `double omkrets = radie*2*3.14;`

Comment: get the following error message then  required: double
  found:    String

Comment: Because toString() returns a String, change your method return type from double to String.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string beraknaOmkrets()
{
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.0");    
    return f.format(radie*2*3.14).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the method is a double, and your returning a string(because your calling `.toString();`. You could change it to be like:

```
public double beraknaOmkrets()
{
  double omkrets = 0;
  omkrets = radie*2*3.14;
  return omkrets;

}
```

And then have a string method like:

```
public String beraknaOmkretsFormatted(double omkrets)
{
      DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.0");
      return f.format(omkrets).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doubles and floats are numbers. They don't carry a format along with them.

```
4.100 = 4.100000
```

To format a float or double, you have to create a string for it. As you did, but your method returns double in the signature.

Answer (score 0):

return type of your method is double while you are returning a string.
Change your return type of the method to String and also there is no need to initialize it to 0 since within that scope , your changing the value in next line.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You will need `DecimalFormat`

```
public double beraknaOmkrets()
{


    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.0");

    double omkrets = 0;
    omkrets = f.format(radie*2*3.14);
    return omkrets;

}
```